# incomplete installation

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

While upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04, my /boot partition filled & the
upgrade failed. I now lack a /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-119-generic, which the
upgrade was trying to create when it failed.

The system booted anyway. I'm afraid to reboot as things stand. /initrd.img
points to /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-119-generic, which doesn't exist.

What to do?